# Display all the data in the same page using Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to display all the data present in the DB in same page where my form is present.I have saved one record.Please help me to show all the data after submit in that same page.

My code are as follows.

## views/users/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :users,:url => {:action => 'create'} do |f| %>
<p>
    Name: <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p>
    Email: <%= f.email_field :email %>
</p>
<p>
    content: <%= f.text_field :content %>
</p>
<p>
     <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
</p>
<% end %>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

## controller/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @users=User.new
    end
    def create
        @users=User.new(params[:users])
        if @users.save
            flash[:notice]="User has created"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'index'
        else
            flash[:alert]="User couldnot created"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'index'
        end
    end
end
```

I want to show in the same index page after submitting the form using Rails 3.Please help me.

Comment: I don't see any reason to have a `User.new` in your index, do you use it anywhere?

Comment: ok, so in the accepted answer it needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

**views/users/index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :user,:url => {:action => 'create'} do |f| %>
<p>
    Name: <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p>
    Email: <%= f.email_field :email %>
</p>
<p>
    content: <%= f.text_field :content %>
</p>
<p>
     <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
</p>
<% end %>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |u| %>
      <td> <%= u.name%> </td>
      <td> <%= u.email%> </td>
      <td> <%= u.content%> </td>
      <td> <%= link_to 'Show', u %> </td>
      <td> <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(u) %> </td>
      <td> <%= link_to 'Destroy', u, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' } %> </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**controller/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @users=User.all
    end
    def create
        @users=User.new(params[:users])
        if @users.save
            flash[:notice]="User has created"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'index'
        else
            flash[:alert]="User couldnot created"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'index'
        end
    end
end
```